# Convert progressbar steps to pixels in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, progress-bar

I've implemented a simple progressbar in javascript using the html 5 canvas element. The progressbar should be able to show 100 steps. (0-100%)
The progressbar should be able to have variable size, which can bet set by the user.
So, for every step I draw a rectangle.

For example:
 - The progressbar canvas has a width of 100px.
 - On every step I draw a new one pixel wide block.

The problem:
 - The progressbar canvas has a width of 550px.
 - The step-block-size would be 5.5px (550/steps)
 - I'm unable to draw half pixels. If I use Math.floor or Math.Round the progressbar won't be filled out complete at 100% or it will be "overfilled".

How can I solve that problem?

```
var percWidth = Math.round(canvas.width / 100);

for (var i = 0; i<= percentage; i++)
{

var r,g,b;
if (i <= 50)
{
   r = 255;
   g = Math.round((255*i)/50);
   b = 0;
}
else
{
   r = Math.round((255*(100-i))/50);
   g = 255;
   b = 0
 }

 context.fillStyle = "rgb("+r+", "+g+", "+b+")";
 context.fillRect((i*percWidth), 0, (1*percWidth), canvas.height);

}
```

Comment: Use `.ceil()` instead. It'll round up to the next integer for any fractional values.

Comment: But won't ceil() round to 6px? At 100%, it'll fill for 600px (and at 92%, the bar will be completely filled).

Comment: Sorry, but this behaves also like .round() in my case. It "overfills" the bar. The answer from Konerak worked fine. Nevertheless, thanks!

Comment: I have to wait for 4 minutes, till I can accept your answer. (Don't ask me why...)
And which previous question? The one about WM6.5? It still isn't solved. ;)

p.s.: If you like to have look on the progressbar - visit: http://wortkonstrukte.net/undtschuess/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only round the final result:

```
context.fillRect(Math.round(i*canvas.width / 100), 0, (percWidth), canvas.height);
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this isn't directly applicable to your question -- but is the `<progress>` a suitable substitute?